# What did Eddie do with the rest of the cocaine?

Tags: the-dark-tower

In Book II, The Drawing of the Three, before the shootout between Roland, Eddie Dean, and Balazar's gang, Eddie was told by Roland, with the narration cut out:

> Now you get exactly as much of the cocaine as you promised the man Balazar. No more and no less. And we go back.

Eddie had previously promised half of the shipment. What this should have meant is that Eddie brings exactly half of the cocaine into the firefight and probably forgets it on that side when he comes back with Roland. But this leaves the other half of the cocaine unaccounted for. If nobody disturbed it, it was probably lying on the beach and continued lying there while Eddie was going through severe withdrawal, which doesn't make any sense.

What happened to the cocaine?

EDIT: Small aside, for the purposes of spoilers, kindly keep answers and comments relevant to Book II only if possible. Some of us still haven't read any further.

Comment: *Why did you do that Karen!?*

Comment: Oh, jeez, should specify I've only just finished Book II. Kindly keep it applicable to this book only, please.

Comment: I contacted Robin Furth (King's research assistant, writer of the DT comics, and the author of the *Complete Compendium* to the DT).  I'll update when she responds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR:  It is still sitting in a crack in the rocks on the beach near the spot where Roland found the door marked "The Prisoner".

---

### In-Universe:

Eddie left it on the beach.  He was addicted to heroin, not cocaine. Cocaine is a stimulant. Heroin is an opioid. Cocaine will do nothing for a heroin addict in withdrawal. Roland even senses that - although he doesn't know what cocaine or heroin are - it is clear that Eddie is not addicted to cocaine.

While they are on the plane and Roland is inside Eddie's mind, we read this (Roland's dialogue is in italics, as in the original;  bold is mine):

> *I don’t know that word. But I do know that those army women know you are carrying...*
>
> There was a pause. A feeling — odder beyond telling — of phantom fingers rummaging through his brain as if he were a living card catalogue.
>
> *. . . heroin or cocaine. I can’t tell which except — **except it must be cocaine because you’re carrying the one you don’t take to buy the one you do.***
>   - The Drawing of the Three

Roland has access to Eddie's thoughts, of course, so he understands all of it pretty well, despite not knowing what coke or smack are.

> **The prisoner had gone somewhere and gotten a drug. Not the drug he himself took**, nor one that would help cure the gunslinger’s sick body, but one that people paid a lot of money for because it was against the law. **He would give this drug to his brother, who would in turn give it to a man named Balazar. The deal would be complete when Balazar traded them the kind of drug they took for this one**...
>   - *ibid*

Of course, the deal with Balazar goes bad very quickly, and things get even worse when Roland and Eddie return to the beach, so it is likely that neither of the men ever thought about the coke again after the gunfight.  Roland hides it:

> **Roland pushed the bags of devil-dust into the cleft between two rocks and covered them with handfuls of sparse saw-grass.** With that done he rested briefly, head thumping like a hot bag of waters, skin alternately hot and cold, then rolled back through the doorway into that other world, that other body, leaving the increasingly deadly infection behind for a little while.
>   -  *ibid*

And later, we see it one last time, after which it is never mentioned again:

> *Sugar... white... powder...*
>
> **The gunslinger’s eyes wandered to the bags, barely visible under the grass he had tossed over them, and wondered briefly if the stuff in this drink and the stuff in the bags might be one and the same.**
>   -  *ibid*

Soon, Roland is dying (again) and Eddie at least *feels* like he, too, is dying.  Roland needs antibiotics and <del>astin</del> aspirin;  Eddie <del>needs</del> wants heroin;  no one has any use for the cocaine.

In short, Eddie left the cocaine on the beach because it was useless to him.

The comics follow the same course:

[image]
[image]
[image]
- *Dark Tower:  Drawing of the Three:  The Prisoner*, Issue #2

---

### Out-of-Universe:

I was surprised to find that at least one study found that cocaine use *may* reduce symptoms of withdrawal from opioids, presumably including heroin:

> In a 6-month randomized trial comparing 125 opiate-dependent patients who were assigned to four treatment groups (2 or 6 mg of buprenorphine and 35 or 65 mg of methadone), we examined the effects of cocaine use on opiate withdrawal symptoms measured on a 25-item scale on which the scores range from 0 to 75. For the methadone-maintained patients receiving the relatively low dose (35 mg), weekly withdrawal symptoms were highest when the urine toxicology for that week indicated no cocaine use. Similar associations were found for buprenorphine. Thus, when using cocaine at a low maintenance opiate dose, persistent opiate withdrawal symptoms were reduced, which is consistent with previous naloxone-precipitated withdrawal studies. Interestingly, with a higher dose of buprenorphine (6 mg), cocaine may have increased opiate withdrawal symptoms, suggesting a possible mechanism for the reduction of illicit cocaine abuse also recently observed in another study in patients treated with high dose (120 mg) methadone maintenance. This has led to a two-component model for the relationship between cocaine and opiate withdrawal-like symptoms at high versus low opiate maintenance dose. This two-component model also reconciles the contradictory findings of prior studies.
>   -  [National Institutes of Health](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7832179)

However, this study focused on opioid addicts who were *still using* opiods - either methadone, buprenorphine, or both - whereas Eddie was going cold turkey in a world with no heroin.

We might assume that King wasn't aware of this.  He certainly couldn't have known about this study, which was conducted in 1994, when he was writing DotT in 1986-87.